# Path based signalling with dual-sided stations

Tags: openttd

I have just been introduced to Path Based Signalling (referred to as PBS) by a friend, and no matter how much I read I can't seem to figure out how to get a station to work properly which has trains coming in from both sides.

I have ended up with using `Path Signal` behind each platform entrance to 'terminate' the reserved train paths to allow other trains to reserve a path across the signal block. I have included a screenshot to better illustrate my current way of working with these new signals.

I have circled the `One-Way Path Signal`s to highlight them.

[image: OpenTTD dual-sided PBS station]

As you can see, this setup works okay as the first trains reserved path is terminated allowing the second train (grain/livestock) to enter the station.

I'd like to know is this optimal, or even correct usage of these signals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track (pun not intended).

There are just a few minor improvements you can make to this station:

- It doesn't seem like there is a way for your left most track to actually reach the 'out' line at the bottom right of the screen without going through a lot of bends.
- Its not optimal to have both the in and out lines share a common path as that can cause a lot of backup, especially if you have a slow train.
- Avoid unnecessary turns in your tracks as that causes slowdown as well.

My favorite type of station to use is a ["Ro-Ro" station](https://wiki.openttd.org/en/Manual/Railway%20station#ro-ro) where trains entering and leaving don't interfere with each other.

This is the simplest version to build and easiest to extend to whatever size station you want:

[image: station image]
<sub>(source: [openttd.org](https://wiki.openttd.org/images/2/2e/8_platform_station.PNG))</sub>

The same concept can also be applied to dual sided stations:

[image: station image 2]
<sub>(source: [openttd.org](https://wiki.openttd.org/images/0/04/High_throughput_Ro-ro_station.png))</sub>

Comment: Wow, I was hoping for a simpler solution, but I do understand how this works. I'm still not sure why there are only one-way signals on one side of the station, as it looks like trains could us both sides?

Comment: @davidyell sometimes you only have one side to work with, such as deep inside a city where you can't afford to have a dual sided staton

Comment: I'm keen to understand why in the blue station there are dual sided signals on the NE side of the station, but only single signals on the SW side.

Comment: If there is a savegame with this setup that I can look at - that would be epic!

Comment: @DavidYell i made a quicky example with 2 roros, you can get it here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=37173294977205686476

Comment: @DavidYell The entrance/exit on the right side is done using pre-signals, and on the left side it is using PBS.  It is probably an illustration created at one time to show the difference between the two signal approaches.